# M-Bus level converter

Tags: rs232, bus

Hello I am looking for an M-bus level converter. It has to support rs232 for hooking it up to a raspi. I have 5 slaves so 20 unit loads should be sufficient. I am not able to find a suitable product on the internet which costs max. 100 euros. Has anyone a hint or a link?
[This](https://www.solvimus.de/m-bus-produkte/) is what I found in another question here. But I don't know if they sell to private customers.

Comment: Shopping is off-topic.

Comment: where would I ask such a question? Can you point me to any forum on the internet?

Comment: Sorry, no idea (but that doesn't make it any less off-topic here).